# Start symbols in Happy with GLR mode

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy, glr

Suppose I define a happy grammar

```
%name pf f
%tokentype { AB }

%error { parseError }

%token
    a { A }
    b { B }
%%

f : 
  a g a {}
  | b {}
g :
   b b {}

{
data AB = A | B deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
parseError _ = error " bad "
}
```

If I compile this with

```
happy --glr
```

I am interested in generally in grammars with non-trivial ambiguities; however, this example demonstrates the bit that is confusing me.

I get a Haskell parser.  I get a success only when the token stream is 
    a b b a
    or
    b

However, I am much more interested in failure.  I would like to fail very fast, and I seem to need to more tokens than I would think would be required.

For example, if I feed the token stream a,a,a ... it takes to the third a to fail.  If I feed b b b, it takes to the third b to fail.  Why the extra lookahead?  When matching f, once I see two 'a's, there is nothing in the grammar that can match.

Comment: In fact, if I modify this tokentype to be ABCD = A | B| C | D, and modify tokens to c { C }; d { D }, and add a parser h : c {}... then the generated parser requires to 'c's and two 'd's to fail.  The token 'd' is completely unused, and happy recognizes that 'c' is unused by f.  So I am even more confused.

Comment: One further clarification: The problem is with parsing streams.  I submit "a" "a" and then close the stream, or "c" and close the stream, I do indeed get failure.  The only tricky thing is submitting the stream lazily.